# C# forms Processing multiple things

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some pictureboxes in the form in a List. I want them to update their position and still being able to drag the object while updating the others.

I'm doing and infinitive while loop the keep updating their positions:

```
while (true)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    pictures[0].Location = new Point(pictures[0].Location.X - rnd.Next(-2, 3), pictures[0].Location.Y + rnd.Next(0, 2));
    pictures[1].Location = new Point(pictures[1].Location.X, pictures[1].Location.Y + 1);
    this.Update();
}
```

The problem is that I've made this elements draggable, but the MouseDown event is not being called. Because of the infinity loop I guess, but how can I fix that ?

Comment: You have to take care when modifying UI elements from within a thread (JonasH sugested a Timer, which is also good), or you will get an exception...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=net-5.0). Set it to trigger however often you want to update the positions. This lets the main thread process other events, while updating your animation as often as needed.

How to create a timer:

```
   myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
   myTimer.Tick += TimerEventProcessor;

   // Sets the timer interval to 0.5 seconds.
   myTimer.Interval = 500;
   myTimer.Start();
```

and

```
private void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject,
                                        EventArgs myEventArgs) {
// Your update code here
}
```